What bolt is missing and can I just buy one and replace it
I have a 04 Chevy Venture 3.4 and it has always had a slight oil leak but couldn’t tell where it was coming from. As I was filling up my oil I noticed a bolt is no missing from my engine. Not sure how long it has been missing and it doesn’t seem to be affecting anything but I would like to fix it and see if it helps with my oil leak or not. Can I just go to a junkyard and get it or is there a bolt I can get from an auto parts store? Should I get some thread lock also and if so what type. I’m including a pic 

My guess, it has a 10mm head on it. :o)

Just going out on a limb here - but your oil "leak" is right next to your dipstick and your oil fill cap. As the car is a 2004 I would guess that these are just drips from filling oil and pulling out the dipstick.
As far as the bolt hole - it looks to me like it's just there to hold a clip or ground strap down.

There is a wire harness next to the bolt hole, maybe there used to be a clip to hold that harness down.
There is a loose ground strap looking thing in the top of your image, does that strap reach the bolt hole?

I wouldn't have any apprehension about sticking a bolt in there. Try to find a similar bolt nearby on your engine. Carefully remove it (don't force it! if it's seized find another bolt or just don't do this) and gently test it in that hole to see if the threads are correct. Test the depth of the hole with a skinny screwdriver. Now you know the threads and depth, go to hardware store and pick up a bolt. Once you have your new bolt, put the other bolt you removed back in!
P.S. don't remove a bolt which looks like it's vital. If you don't know which bolts are vital - don't bother! There isn't a single '04 anything on the road without an oil leak.

Consider to find another vehicle of the same type. Ask the owner to view the engine. It's possible that the hole you see may be used only in certain configurations and does not require a bolt.
You may also wish to research the engine specifications to determine if other vehicle models use the same engine.
Drain holes point downward, not upward, and it's unlikely that is the source of your leak.
Until you are certain that you require a bolt for the hole, do not use thread lock adhesive.
